# smtp connection raises Non-integer base36 conversion input

Tags: python, django, smtp

I am updating a Python / Django app. There is a mailing part to it.

Its throwing the following error:

```
smtp connection raises Non-integer base36 conversion input.
```

Google did not help much.

Comment: If you don't include the full traceback it makes it harder to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the error is from [this line](https://github.com/emencia/emencia-django-newsletter/blob/master/emencia/django/newsletter/mailer.py#L227).

The error is likely caused by the base-36 conversion failing: https://github.com/emencia/emencia-django-newsletter/blob/master/emencia/django/newsletter/utils/tokens.py#L30

Take a closer look at the contact ID. It needs to be an integer. It cannot be `"12"` for example. It should be `12`. Try to modify the code to print out the ID or set a breakpoint using [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to see what it is.